# How can I use SSH with a SOCKS 5 proxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, ssh, cygwin, socks

I have a SOCKS5 proxy set up through PuTTY with port 7777 configured as a dynamic port.  I can use firefox/filezilla/etc by configuring them to use a SOCKS proxy with `localhost` and port `7777`.  But I can't figure out how to ssh (through Cygwin) to a remote server by using the dynamic port.  Is this possible?

I've tried using `ProxyCommand` via the following method.

1. Create `~/.ssh/config` with the following line:

   ```
   ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X connect -x 127.0.0.1:7777 %h %p
   ```
2. Run ssh -p22 user@remotehost

The message I get is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: To make a program whuch does not support SOCKS go through SOCKS, you can use a so-called proxifer; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers . In particular, I recommand my open source tun2socks proxifer ( http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks ).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ambroz.  I need it to work in cygwin, and I see from the wikipedia page on proxifiers that all of the ones it mentions are either not implemented in cygwin or not applicable.  Is there a way to get a proxifier to work in cygwin?

Comment: you don't need it to specifically support Cygwin. Cygwin programs are in the end just Windows programs, but with a POSIX interface implemented as a library. If a proxifier works on Windows, it should be able to proxify Cygwin programs just fine.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You are using 'connect' for HTTPS as your proxy version, this is from man nc:

> -X proxy_version Requests that nc should use the specified protocol when talking to the proxy server. Supported protocols are ''4'' (SOCKS v.4), ''5'' (SOCKS v.5) and 'connect' (HTTPS proxy). If the protocol is not specified, SOCKS version 5 is used.

So you should use the following to use SOCKS 5:

```
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:7777 %h %p
```

Or simply:

```
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc -x 127.0.0.1:7777 %h %p
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Saman, that worked!  Also, thanks for the explanation, it helps.

Comment: The `ProxyCommand` must be the first line of your `~/.ssh/config', or else nested inside a specify `Host` section. Not really sure why. It doesn't work if it's the last line in the `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: From `man ssh_config`: "For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used."  Therefore... global settings need to be **before** any `Host` sections.  The last line of `~/.ssh/config` is part of the final `Host` section.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that netcat is in `/bin/nc` on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: Worth noting that `netcat-traditional` doesn't work. Install `netcat-openbsd` for this purpose.

Answer (score 18):

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc --proxy-type socks4 --proxy 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p' user@host
```

fc19 x86_64, Ncat: Version 6.25

Comment: just curious - why `proxy-type socks4`?

Comment: Can you add a little more explanation to this to say *why* it's the solution.

Comment: @ChrisF it is the same as accepted solution, but it is one-liner! No need to modify any config file.

Comment: On Gentoo, right command name is `ncat` and not `nc` like on other distros.

Comment: This is the [nmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap) `ncat` program (comes via `apt install nmap` on APT systems like Ubuntu and Debian), which is different from [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) (be it netcat-openbsd or Hobbit's netcat-traditional).

Comment: @suspectus related to @Adam Katz comment, the `proxy-type` is `socks4` because the nmap `ncat` program didn't support sock5 until more recently.  Indeed, this is an issue even now (Nov 2017), as RHEL 7/Centos 7 switched to the nmap package but used an older build that does not support socks5

Comment: on macos: `ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:9050 %h %p' user@host`. Otherwise, there will be an error: `nc: unrecognized option `--proxy'`

Answer (score 8):

**tsocks** (http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) is a nice wrapper that uses LD_PRELOAD to make any program use SOCKS proxy transparently:

```
tsocks ssh example.com
```

Just works, remember to configure SOCKS proxy IP in */etc/tsocks.conf*

Comment: it's too complex to have a configuration file

Comment: tsocks is the only solution that worked for me, so I think this is an important answer to maintain here. the tsocks config file is fairly simple

Comment: thanks. it's straightforward to use. just use `export LD_PRELOAD=libtsocks.so`

Answer (score 3):

Just to make it more simple, you could put these in `~/.ssh/config`

```
host = example.com
ProxyCommand nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p
```

Any ssh command in terminal will now get through this proxy.

Comment: it's pity, netcat not support socks5 with username:password

Answer (score 2):

This following command will do, to just use nc:

```
ssh examplehost.com -o "ProxyCommand=nc --proxy localhost:7000 %h %p"
```

Default is HTTP proxy, there is an HTTP proxy running on port 7000.

Comment: `ssh root@server -p 22 -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p"` works

Answer (score 2):

ssh is able to understand `ALL_PROXY` environment variable so apparently something like this

```
ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:9150 ssh example.com
```

does the trick also for me at least.