# Use SSH to Create an HTTP Proxy without browser

Tags: ssh, tunnel, http-proxy

I am trying to reach an HTTP(S) website from my device's browser. My Device can get to that website only through a double SSH tunnel.

Using [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/use-ssh-create-http-proxy) technique, I'm able to set up my Firefox browser to successfully proxy through an SSH tunnel on a server of mine called `SERVER1`.

However, `SERVER1` can't get to the website that I need. Luckily, `SERVER1` can SSH to another `SERVER2` who can.

Now, I could run:

```
SERVER1 $ ssh -D 12345 myuser@SERVER2
```

and create yet another tunnel from `SERVER1` to `SERVER2`, but I'm not clear on how to do the "firefox" part without firefox on `SERVER1`.

On top of that, the website is on a non standard port (let's say 8765) so I'm not sure the `export http_proxy` would work.

How would I go about it? Thanks

Comment: You want to look into using a JumpHost - https://ma.ttias.be/use-jumphost-ssh-client-configurations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to chain SOCKS proxies?](https://superuser.com/q/836194/19867)

To chain proxies:
https://superuser.com/a/843766/19867

```
ssh -tt -v -L1234:localhost:12345 user@server1 ssh -t -D 12345 user@server2
```

Answer (score 1):

First setup a `ProxyJump` chain to the target server. this may look like this in your ssh-config

```
Host SERVER2 
ProxyJump SERVER1
```

You can chain more jumphosts by using `ProxyJump jumphost1,jumphost2`

Then use `ssh -D 1234 SERVER2` and set `localhost:1234` as **socks** Proxy in the local firefox.

An alternative is to use `ssh -L` to forward the HTTP port, but can be more complicated when the server uses the hostname for virtual hosts or selection of a TLS certificate.

The nice thing about `ProxyJump` is, that you do not need to think about if when you set it up and all ssh options will work as usual and you can use the hostname as if you could reach it directly.