# How to connect to sftp server from MacOS terminal using a SOCKS5 proxy with username and password?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, proxy, sftp

There are similar questions like this around, but I haven't been able find the answer to my question, which is:

How to connect to sftp server from a MacOS terminal using a SOCKS5 proxy with username and password?

Let's say that I want to connect to this sftp server:

```
Host: somesftpserver.mycompany.com
Username: sftpusername
Password: sftppassword
```

I need to connect to this sftp server from a SOCKS5 proxy:

```
Host: somesocks5proxy.somecompany.com
Username: proxyusername
Password: proxypassword
```

How can I do this from the terminal in MacOS? I'm fine with installing third-party tools  (as long as they don't require any payment) such as Putty's `psftp`.

Comment: I've seen that, but it doesn't work when I've tried to modify the example(s) to use username/password.

Comment: If you have seen/tried something already, you should have told us upfront. Please include everything you have already tried and failed into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use SSH with a SOCKS 5 proxy?](https://superuser.com/questions/454210/how-can-i-use-ssh-with-a-socks-5-proxy)